# run lambda function only once, the time set to 5 minutes later

Tags: python, aws-lambda, boto3, terraform

I have a request to set a lambda function to initialize a RDS database, but only run once

My plan is to deploy rds and lambda function together within one module, but set to run the lambda function 5 minutes later, only once. So I can guarantee the RDS is active status.

I can't set `local-exec` or `remote-exec`, because our company's proxy server. Terraform doesn't use openssh/openssl in their Golang codes, 
 then terraform doesn't understand `~/.ssh/config`

Any ideas to set the run once lambda function after 5 minutes and ignore the change later.

[timestamp() in terraform](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#timestamp-) can generate the time, timeadd() can be used to generate the time for 5 minutes later.

```
output "time" {
  value = "${timeadd(timestamp(), "5m")}"
}
```

But it will be hard to convert to `cron(Minutes Hours Day-of-month Month Day-of-week Year)`. My feeling I should not do this in Terraform directly.

#### Update 1

I am going to add an environment variable (`EXECUTE_TIMESTAMP`) to lambda function. Will confirm later if this helps or not.

So the lambda will check the `timestamp` if not passed, or more than 1 hour, it will ignore the rest tasks. This lambda function will be scheduled to run per hour.

Then, one day if I want to re-run this lambda function, I can adjust that variable easily.

#### Update 2

[A PR](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/pull/17625) was raised for this time output format feature But it is not merged currently.

Not sure if the new feature supports cron formation as output or not.

Comment: How about send an SQS event once, manually, to trigger the lambda?

Comment: looks a good idea. I can even feed the sql scripts directly as message in file.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not going to be doing it much, it's worth nothing that lambda has a maximum timeout of 15 minutes these days.

So while it's not the best piece of architecture, for a simple and infrequent "dev"-script, you could simply start the lambda at the same time as your RDS deployment and have it wait (`time.sleep(300)`) for 5 minutes in code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `null_resource`(has local-exec of 5min sleep) which `depends_on` and `trigger` on RDS creation. And make lambda `depends_on` above `null_resource`.

This way, your lambda function will only be invoked once after 5min of RDS creation.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be to invoke a state machine that will wait 5 minutes before invoking your Lambda.